# SQL Server count case

Tags: sql-server, count, case

I have table in SQL Server with values for example :

```
1
2
2
2
1
2
```

I want to count how many times there is `1` value, so result of query from my example should be 2

I try

```
count (case status_d when 1 then 1 end) as COUNT_STATUS_1
```

but the result is 4, not 2

Comment: The query you have should work.

Comment: You query returns 2 in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f25b6).

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve this by using a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As Total_Ones
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ColumnName = 1
```

Or you can use the case statement as well

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As Total_Ones
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Wouldn't SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) be nicer on the second example?

Comment: Dont think it will make any difference since in either case it will add 1 to returned value.

Comment: COUNT(CASE ...) was not working for me I needed to change it to SUM(CASE...)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM YourTable
WHERE status_d = 1
```